# Keyword - debugger | A practical example

Tags: javascript

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger).

> Invokes any available debugging functionality. If no debugging
>   functionality is available, this statement has no effect.

I've debugged in IE, Safari, and FF and have found no need for this keyword.  Does it have a practical use?  Can someone provide a practical example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing debugger; into your code triggers the same functionality as setting a breakpoint in the debugging utility.  I have had various debugging utilities not show the script because of using a script inside a cms or other unknown reasons.  However the scripts still halted and allowed me to check the state of variables where ever i used debugger;

This may be a stretch of a practical example but i have found a use for it.

Technically

```
debugger;
```

appears to be a manual or coding way to trigger a debug utility as opposed to setting a break point inside of a debug utility.  Hope this helps.

Comment: It's been a year since i have used this method.  I dont remeber which utility.  But yes i was able to use the utility after that.