# Difficulty with jquery in Forms

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form and when I am submitting the value of my variables is coming null.
Any idea what can be?

My code:

```
            $('#botaoSalvar').click(function () {
                $('form').trigger('submit');
            });

            $('form').submit(function () {
                if (defaults.tipoAcao == 2) {
                    var retorno = ($('form').serialize());
                } else {
                    var retorno = nomeidRegistro + '=' + idRegistro + '&' + ($(this).serialize());
                }
                debugger
                return retorno;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="alterarDados" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" style="display: block;" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false"><h3>Alterar Registro</h3>
 <form id="formAlterar" action="/teste/index3" method="post">
    <div id="corpoTabelaAlterar"><tr id="atributo2">
    <td><label for="DescricaoBaseDados">DescricaoBaseDados:</label>
    </td><td><input type=" name=" descricaobasedados"="" value="1">
    </td></tr><tr id="atributo3"><td><label for="NomeBaseDados">NomeBaseDados:</label>
    </td><td><input type=" name=" nomebasedados"="" value="1">
    </td></tr><tr><td><input id="botaoVoltar" type="button" value="Voltar" name="voltar">
    </td><td><input id="botaoSalvar" type="submit" value="Salvar" name="salvar">
    </td></tr></div><table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" width="450" id="tabelaAlterar">

    </table>
  </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Which variables in particular are returning null?

Comment: It looks like you're overriding the jquery submit, but not calling the form submit.  I'm not certain that's what it is, but it's the first place I'd look.  I also admit curiosity as to what the "debugger" command does.  Beyond that, we'd really want to see the html of the form (as Siddharth pointed out)

Comment: @BenBarden http://stackoverflow.com/a/12503311/1331430

Comment: `<input type=" name=" descricaobasedados"="" value="1">` appears to have some issues in it... it's missing a type and the name attribute has some weird quote problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some errors in your code:

```
</td><td><input type=" name=" descricaobasedados"="" value="1">
</td></tr><tr id="atributo3"><td><label for="NomeBaseDados">NomeBaseDados:</label>
</td><td><input type=" name=" nomebasedados"="" value="1">
```

Your `type` attribute is not set above. You've also got an error in the syntax of the `name` attribute. It should follow a format more like the following:

```
<input type="text" name="descricaobasedados" value="1">
```

Replace the `type` with whatever `type` you are using.

I don't know if this is all of your problem but I'm sure it is definitely contributing. Inputs in a form are posted (submitted) using the `name` attribute. If the attribute is not properly defined, you may receive `null` values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should have answered the question instead of putting this as a comment :p  oh well!

Comment: Lol. All good. I actually had mine as a comment and decided to copy and paste it as an answer instead.